# dynamic filters (predicate) in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am writing an app for iOS using SwiftUI and CoreData. I am trying to solve one problem for a few days now. How to make dynamic filters using dynamically changing predicate in SwiftUI based on user input?

I have followed this tutorial to learn about dynamic filters and CoreData: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

After few small changes I have the following code.
**ContentView.swift**:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @State var lastNameFilter = "A"

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            FilteredList(predicate: lastNameFilter)

            Button("Add Examples") {
                let taylor = Singer(context: self.moc)
                taylor.firstName = "Taylor"
                taylor.lastName = "Swift"

                let ed = Singer(context: self.moc)
                ed.firstName = "Ed"
                ed.lastName = "Sheeran"

                let adele = Singer(context: self.moc)
                adele.firstName = "Adele"
                adele.lastName = "Adkins"

                try? self.moc.save()
            }

            Button("Show A") {
                self.lastNameFilter = "A"
            }

            Button("Show S") {
                self.lastNameFilter = "S"
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**FilteredList.swift**:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct FilteredList: View {

    var predicate:String
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Singer>
    var singers: FetchedResults<Singer>{fetchRequest.wrappedValue}

    var body: some View {
        List(singers, id: \.self) { singer in
            Text("\(singer.firstName ?? "Unknown") \(singer.lastName ?? "Unknown")")
        }
    }

    init(predicate: String) {
        self.predicate = predicate
        self.fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Singer>(entity: Singer.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "lastName BEGINSWITH %@", predicate))
    }

}

//struct FilteredList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
//    static var previews: some View {
//    }
//}
```

I also have 1 entity named **Singer** and this entity has 2 attributes: **firstName** and **lastName**, both of which are Strings.
Above example seems to work fine in Simulator, but crashes the app when using Preview in Xcode.

**I would appreciate any help, for example:**

- pointing which part of my example code to change to avoid errors in Preview
- simple example of another way of using dynamic predicates in SwiftUI
- link to a tutorial on dynamic filters in SwiftUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To make the preview of ContentView work you should write something like the following:

```swift
static var previews: some View {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let taylor = Singer(context: context)
    taylor.firstName = "Taylor"
    taylor.lastName = "Swift"
    let ed = Singer(context: context)
    ed.firstName = "Ed"
    ed.lastName = "Sheeran"
    let adele = Singer(context: context)
    adele.firstName = "Adele"
    adele.lastName = "Adkins"
    return ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
}
```

2. You could implement a more generic FilteredList type where you only provide the predicate for the list (optionally a sort descriptor). Example:

```swift
struct FilteredList<T: NSManagedObject, Content: View>: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<T>
    var items: FetchedResults<T> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

    let content: (T) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            self.content(item)
        }
    }

    init(predicate: NSPredicate?, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor] = [], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<T>(entity: T.entity(), sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate)
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Use this new `FilteredList` type with `@State private var predicate: NSPredicate?` instead of `@State var lastNameFilter = "A"`. When new filtering is needed just set this private @State property to the new predicate and the list will be updated accordingly.

The concrete usage would be:

```swift
FilteredList(predicate: predicate) { (singer: Singer) in
    Text("\(singer.firstName ?? "") \(singer.lastName ?? "")")
}
```

Preview of the FilteredList:

```swift
static var previews: some View {
    FilteredList(predicate: nil) { (singer: Singer) in
        Text("\(singer.firstName ?? "") \(singer.lastName ?? "")")
    }.environment(\.managedObjectContext, (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Gergely. Your 1st answer helped me to get rid of the error! :) As for 2nd answer - this sounds very promising. But I have a problem with implementation. On line `self.predicate = "S"` I am getting an error `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSPredicate?'`

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I needed to use `self.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName BEGINSWITH %@", "S")` instead of `self.predicate = "A"` :) One last problem. How should I define `content: <#(T) -> Content#>` in FilteredList_Previews to make it work?

Comment: @mallow Updated my answer with the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct FilteredList: View {

    @FetchRequest var singers: FetchedResults<Singer>

    init(lastName: String) {
        _singers = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "lastName BEGINSWITH %@", lastName))
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(singers) { singer in
            Text("\(singer.firstName ?? "Unknown") \(singer.lastName ?? "Unknown")")
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that every time the View is init and the FetchRequest is init the database is hit so you may need to lift the fetch into a superview.