# How do I apply a dynamic search text filter to a SwiftUI list using CoreData?

Tags: swift, list, search, filter, uisearchbar

My Struct contains...

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.priority, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
```

So '**Item**' is of type **NSManagedObject**.

```
 // MARK: - FOREACH
       
      ForEach(self.itemsList, id: \.self){ item in
          HStack {
                 Text(item.name ?? "Name")
                 Spacer()
                 Text(item.priority ?? "Priority")
                  }
      }//: FOREACH
```

I use a ForEach to extract the detail I need for a SwiftUI List.

However, I would like to use a **UISearchBar** text filter to filter this SwiftUI list but as I am using CoreData and an NSMangedObject, I am just not sure how to do this.

If it was a simple String Array, there are many examples online using a **.filter** command, but I cannot find examples online for filtering NSManagedObjects.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic filters (predicate) in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501638/dynamic-filters-predicate-in-swiftui)

Comment: There are [many questions on this subject in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swiftui+dynamic+predicate+fetchrequest)